How to reduce the space between elements of a bslib grid?
How can I reduce/eliminate the white space between the 5 actionboxes but keep the spaces between the 2 actionboxes? Preferably also shown how the solution was "found" in Chrome?
library(shiny)
library(bslib)
library(tidyverse)


style <- "font-size:80%; padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0; text-align:left"

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  card(
    card_header(
      "Plot",
    ),
    plotOutput("plot"),
    card_footer(
      card_body(
        layout_column_wrap(
          actionButton("labels", "Labels", icon = icon("tag"), style = style),
          actionButton("axes", "Axes", icon = icon("lines-leaning"), style = style),
          actionButton("theme", "Theme", icon = icon("palette"), style = style),
          actionButton("options", "Options", icon = icon("sliders"), style = style),
          actionButton("sort", "Select & Sort", icon = icon("sort"), style = style)
        ))),
    card_body(
    layout_column_wrap(actionButton("a", "test"), actionButton("b", "test2"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    
    ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
      geom_point()
    
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


Is adding theme = bs_theme("bslib_spacer" = "0rem") to a page_fluid yielding what you want?

@Jan it does, but can can I apply it inline or only to those 5 boxes?

What exactly do you mean with this question? This is a global variable which defines the gap in a bslib-grid.

I only want to remove the gap for those actionBoxes. If I add it to my "real" shiny app, it removes all the gaps and some I want to keep.

@Jan I updated my question with a second row of inputs.

Then you could do it like this: Pass an additional class to the desired layout_column_wrap, e.g. class = "myGrid". This makes it possible that you can target this specific grid. And then you add css which defines the gap for this class: tags$head(tags$style(HTML(".myGrid { gap: 0rem; }"))).

@Jan Worked great, thanks!

You are welcome. Shall I write an answer with that? Is something missing?

Please write an answer. I did get some issues when I tried using it together with dropMenu but I created a separate question for that.

The space between elements in a bslib grid, e.g. created by using layout_column_wrap, can be controlled by adjusting the scss variable --bslib_spacer which defaults to 1rem. Hence, one can set up a theme using another value, e.g. like this:
page_fluid(
  theme = bs_theme("bslib_spacer" = "0rem"),
  ...
)

However, this works globally and in your setup you need to distinguish this between different grids. This could be done by passing a gap parameter to layout_column_wrap. From ?layout_column_wrap:

gap: A CSS length unit defining the gap (i.e., spacing) between elements
provided to .... This argument is only applicable when fillable = TRUE

library(shiny)
library(bslib)

style <- "font-size:80%; padding-top: 0; padding-bottom: 0; text-align:left"

ui <- page_fluid(
  card(
    card_footer(
      card_body(
        layout_column_wrap(
          actionButton("labels", "Labels", icon = icon("tag"), style = style),
          actionButton("axes", "Axes", icon = icon("lines-leaning"), style = style),
          actionButton("theme", "Theme", icon = icon("palette"), style = style),
          actionButton("options", "Options", icon = icon("sliders"), style = style),
          actionButton("sort", "Select & Sort", icon = icon("sort"), style = style),
          gap = "0rem"
        ))),
    card_body(
      layout_column_wrap(actionButton("a", "test"), actionButton("b", "test2"))
    )
  )
)

shinyApp(ui, \(...){})


